# azcopy sync fails with not authorized error

Tags: azcopy

I am trying to sync a local documentation folder to the destination container at Azure blob storage for a static site. Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer works great - transfers local files to $web. I am now trying to speed it up using the Powershell CLI. I am able to login, but the sync command throws a AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error. The command I am using [based on the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize) is:

```
azcopy sync "./Documents/sphinx/_build/html" "https://edvision.blob.core.windows.net/$web?[SAS]"
```

More details below:

```
PS C:\Users\magrawal> azcopy login
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXXXX to authenticate.
INFO: Logging in under the "Common" tenant. This will log the account in under its home tenant.
INFO: If you plan to use AzCopy with a B2B account (where the account's home tenant is separate from the tenant of the target storage account), please sign in under the target tenant with --tenant-id
INFO: Login succeeded.

PS C:\Users\magrawal> azcopy sync "./Documents/sphinx/_build/html" "https://edvision.blob.core.windows.net/$web?[SAS]"
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job e36cdff1-cc77-7248-73b9-765152f1bf8b has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\magrawal\.azcopy\e36cdff1-cc77-7248-73b9-765152f1bf8b.log

0 Files Scanned at Source, 0 Files Scanned at Destination
Cannot perform sync due to error: cannot list files due to reason -> github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, /home/vsts/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.10.1-0.20210407023846-16cf969ec1c3/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ServiceCode=AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) =====
Description=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:ebb87f15-e01e-0052-7957-654794000000
Time:2021-06-19T22:10:30.9307497Z, Details:
Code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
GET https://edvision.blob.core.windows.net/%5BSAS%5D?comp=list&delimiter=%2F&include=metadata&restype=container&timeout=901
Authorization: REDACTED
User-Agent: [AzCopy/10.11.0 Azure-Storage/0.13 (go1.15; Windows_NT)]
X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [0678b644-7cd9-4b24-52fe-3c6fd150e72f]
X-Ms-Version: [2019-12-12]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE Status: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
Content-Length: [279]
Content-Type: [application/xml]
Date: [Sat, 19 Jun 2021 22:10:30 GMT]
Server: [Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]
X-Ms-Client-Request-Id: [0678b644-7cd9-4b24-52fe-3c6fd150e72f]
X-Ms-Error-Code: [AuthorizationPermissionMismatch]
X-Ms-Request-Id: [ebb87f15-e01e-0052-7957-654794000000]
X-Ms-Version: [2019-12-12]
```

Answer (score 0):

An AuthorizationPermissionMismatch is when the token authorizes, but some operation is not allowed by the token.

You may need the [Storage Blob Data Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) on the storage account.

You can also refer to this link, for more detailed information how [RBAC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4adfa23e-d50a-4f47-ab28-4e674afa5ec9/using-rbac-on-azure-storage?forum=windowsazuredata) works

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the firewall of the storage account that blocked my IP.
After allowing it, worked like a charm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35397903)